# SQL XML output into file automatically

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have the code below and works OK, generates the XML output in SQL Server Management Studio.
How can i save the result into a file on the drive automatically in order to run every night?

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
DECLARE @Rechnungen TABLE (id int , Nummer nvarchar(20), Datum datetime);
INSERT INTO @Rechnungen (id, Nummer, Datum) VALUES 
(8, 'R200001', '2020-06-29');

DECLARE @Rechnungpos TABLE (id int, id_Rechnung int, Anzahl float);
INSERT INTO @RechnungPos (id, id_Rechnung, Anzahl) VALUES 
(1, 8, 3),
(5, 8, 1), 
(9, 8, 2);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @ID_Rechnung int = 8;

WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2' as ext
    , 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2' as cbc
    , 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2' as cac
    , 'http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#' as xades
    , 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as xsi
    , 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#' as ds)
SELECT (
SELECT '2.1'               AS [cbc:UBLVersionID],
    'TR1.2'                AS [cbc:CustomizationID],
    ''                     AS [cbc:ProfileID],
    p.Nummer               AS [cbc:ID],
    'false'                AS [cbc:CopyIndicator],
    ''                     AS [cbc:UUID],
    CAST(p.Datum AS Date)  AS [cbc:IssueDate],
    (
        SELECT c.id AS [cbc:ID]
            , CAST(c.Anzahl AS INT) AS [cbc:InvoicedQuantity] 
        FROM @Rechnungpos AS c INNER JOIN 
            @Rechnungen AS p ON p.id = c.id_Rechnung
        FOR XML PATH('r'), TYPE, ROOT('root')
    )
FROM @Rechnungen AS p
WHERE p.id = @ID_Rechnung
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('Invoice')
).query('<Invoice xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#"
         xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
         xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"
         xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2">
<ext:UBLExtensions>
    <ext:UBLExtension>
        <ext:ExtensionContent/>
    </ext:UBLExtension>
</ext:UBLExtensions>
{
   for $x in /Invoice/*[local-name()!="root"]
   return $x,
     for $x in /Invoice/root/r
     return <cac:InvoiceLine>{$x/*}</cac:InvoiceLine>
}
</Invoice>');
```

Comment: *"How can i save the result into a file on the drive automatically in order to run every night?"* Use a scheduling tool and an ETL layer to run statement, consume the output, and then write it to disc. There are many different tools to do this, but [so] is *not* for recommendations on such; you need to decide what tool(s) you want to use (perhaps you already have some). SQL Server comes with SQL Server Agent, for example (provided you aren't using Express).

Comment: Thanks, i can manage to run automatically, but how to save this result  into a file with sql code?

Comment: You use your ETL layer to write the output to disc; not the SQL layer.

Comment: What have you researched so far. Have you looked at BCP?

Comment: Yes, i was looking to bcp but i could not manage to get the output into a file. Any help would be super.

Comment: You made no mention of this in your question? Output the results of your query into a table then use BCP to output the content of the table.

Comment: Aside... lots of superfluous namespace references in both sides of the query. And `for $x in /Invoice/*[local-name()!="root"]` could be simplified to `for $x in /Invoice/cbc:*`

Comment: Or use a Powershell job in SQL Server Agent: `$rows = Invoke-SqlCmd ..... -As DataRows ; ($rows[0].Columns[0].Value) | Out-File -FilePath yourPathHere;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following solution based on **bcp**.

First, run it as-is to see how it is working.

Later on package your T-SQL in the question as a stored procedure.

And modify the following variable as follows:

```
@SQL VARCHAR(2048) = 'EXEC <your_stored_procedure_name>;'
```

**SQL**

```
/*
-T tells BCP to use Windows Authentication to connect to SQL Server. It will operate as the user who's running the command.
-U <login_id> -P <password> tells BCP to use SQL Server account while connecting to SQL Server.
*/
DECLARE @SQLCmd VARCHAR(8000)
   , @outputFileName VARCHAR(256) = 'e:\Temp\SampleXMLOutput.xml'
   , @bcp VARCHAR(256) = 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\bcp.exe'
   , @SQL VARCHAR(2048) = 'SET NOCOUNT ON; SELECT TOP(1) TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME FROM master.Information_Schema.Tables FOR XML PATH(''r''), TYPE, ROOT(''root'');'
   , @tcpPort VARCHAR(10) = '1433'
   , @WindowsAuth BIT = 1   -- 1 is for Windows Authentication, 0 is for SQL Server Authentication
   , @loginID VARCHAR(100) = 'loginID'
   , @password VARCHAR(100) = 'password'
   , @serverName VARCHAR(100) = 'realServerName';

-- SQL Server 2016 onwards
--SET @SQLCmd = FORMATMESSAGE('START "" "%s" "%s" queryout "%s" -T -x -c -C 1252 -a 65535 -S "%s,%s"'
--            , @bcp
--            , @SQL
--            , @outputFileName
--            , @@SERVERNAME
--            , @tcpPort);

-- older versions of SQL Server
-- /B "WindowTitle" parameters produce output in the SSSMS !!!
SET @SQLCmd = 'START /B "WindowTitle" "' + @bcp + '"' 
            + ' "' + @SQL + '"' 
            + ' queryout "' + @outputFileName + '"'
            --+ IIF(@WindowsAuth = 1, ' -T', ' -U '+ @loginID + ' -P ' + @password)
            + CASE WHEN @WindowsAuth = 1 THEN ' -T'
               ELSE ' -U '+ @loginID + ' -P ' + @password
               END
            + ' -x -c -C 1252 -a 32768'
            + ' -S "' + @serverName + ',' + @tcpPort + '"';

-- just to see it
SELECT @SQLCmd AS [Command to execute];

-- create file on the file system
EXECUTE master.sys.xp_cmdshell @SQLCmd;
```

Answer (score 0):

Or in Powershell like this

```
$t = invoke-sqlcmd "select * from sys.messages for xml path('row'), root('data')"
$sw = new-object system.io.streamwriter "c:\temp\foo.xml"
foreach($r in $t) { $sw.write($r[0]) }
$sw.close()
```